# EF Core import historical data to Temporal Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have daily snapshots of historical data.
Is there a way with EF Core to import these into a Temporal Table with a specified Date where this data was valid?

After some research, the only way I can imagine, is to set the systemtime of the SQL Server to the specified date. That seems pretty awful though as normal queries will return 'old' data as long as the SQL Server has the 'wrong' system time. Also I read about some delay after setting the system time until SQL Server will notice.

The application will be a docker container running an ASP.NET Core application, another docker container running the importer service and a third docker container running SQL Server.

I need to import a lot of historical data until yesterday and update the data on a daily basis in the future.
Its also likely that there will be more datasets to be added in the future where I also have to import historical data.

Thanks!

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: 1) *Is there a way with EF Core to import these into a Temporal Table* - no. 2) Have you tried to insert into history table via SQL?